# How do I encode a single qoute while backslash does not escape it in the JSON?

Tags: php, android, json

Below this is my Json which is valid. I use this JSON to send notifications on Android and iOS devices using SNS. However,

```
{
"default": "", 
"GCM": "{ \"data\": { \"message\": \"{'user_id':'48491','story_title':'Who is Trumps dangerous best friend?','story_slug':'Who-is-Trumps dangerous best friend?','story_id':'40372','user_full_name':'Gourav Choubey','cover_image':'url','user_profile_photo':'url'}\" } }"
}
```

When I add an  ' (Single Qoute) to the title, such as the JSON below, is still a valid JSON but on the Device side, the JSON decode is unable to read the JSON, due to single qoute on also Story_title, and it's key also starts with a single qoute.

But the Android app is unable to show the single qoutation (') and nothing is shown in the notification.

```
{
 "default": "", 
 "GCM": "{ \"data\": { \"message\": \"{'user_id':'48491','story_title':'Who is Trump's dangerous best friend?','story_slug':'Who-is-Trumps dangerous best friend?','story_id':'40372','user_full_name':'Gourav Choubey','cover_image':'url','user_profile_photo':'url'}\" } }"
}
```

I tried HTML encoding, and backslash to escape the single qoute.

However nothing works, without giving an update to the app, how do I make sure the single qoute is correctly sent?

The end device only takes in the string I sent.

Here is my PHP code.

```
  $android_notification_fields = array(
            "user_id" => $result->user_id,
            "story_title" => addslashes($title),
            "story_id" => $result->story_id,
            "user_full_name" => addslashes($result->user_full_name),
            "cover_image" => $result->cover_image,
            'user_profile_photo' => $result->user_profile_photo

        );


      $push_message = '{ "default": "", "GCM":"{\"data\":{\"message\": \"'.str_replace('"', "'", str_replace('\\','',utf8_encode(json_encode($android_notification_fields)))).'\"}}"}';
    print_r($push_message);
    $topic_arn = $this->android_topic_arn;

    }
```

I know this is simple, (I do the backend in PHP). I am trying to solve this from a number of days, any help will be really appreciated. I wanna avoid changing anything on the Android App.

Comment: Are you trying to encode JSON within JSON? Why not just flatten it?

Comment: How does your PHP code look like

Comment: @StuartWagner Yes I tried that.

Comment: @131 I added the PHP code. Thanks.

Comment: well, you have to escape it. twice. (not withstanding that "Trump's" is gramatically wrong in this case, since it means "Trump is" - "Trumps" was right all along)

Comment: @FranzGleichmann Well, this was just an example. How do I escape it twice?

Comment: Why build `$push_message` by hand, why not json_encode it too?

Comment: @DineshGupta the best way? consistently use `json_encode`, and let it handle everything, instead of rolling your own.

Comment: I did try and did not work.

Comment: @DineshGupta Could you share the PHP you had when trying `json_encode`? We can help you debug it since it's likely the best way.

Comment: This is a whole lot of ***inception***, you have JSON inside JSON inside JSON ... kinda. I said "kinda", because single quotes as string boundaries are not valid.